# RMI: many requests, one data

Tags: java, rmi, high-load

I have RMI server with 2 methods: first changes some value in an array, second reads some value. Array is located in the server's memory. And I have a lot of (1-∞) clients, which call these methods. What happens when a few clients try to change the same value at the same time? Server crashes? Or only acces time increased (server makes request queue?) ?

Comment: " Server crushes?" if hardware doesn't support, yes. But it is not directly related to your RMI implementation.

Comment: @Nambari, crashes, sorry)

Comment: Why don't you test it and see what happens?

Comment: After you've ran some tests, then you can post some meaningful stacktraces on your question.

Comment: @ra2085 Because that might only yield an answer for a particular implementation or version. An answer deriving from the specification would be of more general use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens when a few clients try to change the same value at the same time? Server crashes? Or only acces time increased (server makes request queue?) ?

Neither. The RMI Specification carefully states that there are no guarantees about server-side threading. That means that all the calls can execute concurrently. It is up to you to provide any required synchronization.

Comment: Ok, I needed thread-safety, then ConcurrentMap and AtomicInteger.